# Extracting Text from a HTML Table with no Identifier/Name via Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the results generated from this site:
mailtester.com when entering a full email. Take the email address laura.singer@pfizer.com for example. After entering this address and clicking submit, a HTML table thats highlighted green will show up. I want to get the text "Email address is valid" which is the 5th child of the 5th row of this table it seems. However, there are no ids or names, and there are two tables, so its a bit tricky.

This is what I have right now:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 300)
inputEmail=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email")))
inputEmail.clear()
inputEmail.send_keys(email)
inputEmail.submit()
somethin = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table")
somethin = somethin.text
print(somethin)
```

It prints "Email address" which is incorrect. Looks like there are two tables which do not have ids or names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS selector. It basically means find the `TABLE` tag that is a child (>) of an element with an `ID` (#) `content`

```
somethin = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#content > table")
```

Comment: Interesting. That works...even though there are two tables that are the child of "content"

Comment: Yep... `find_element` (singular) only gets the first element and it just happens that the first one is the one you wanted.